# Taxonomy Access Control module - don't display term instead of disabling it

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm using Taxonomy Access Control module to manage allowed categories of content user can create/edit. I want to change default behaviour of this module which disables term which user cannot assign ("black" in this example) but still displays it. 
I know, it can be hidden via CSS or removed via JS, but I want to remove it on the module level.

[image: categories]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the issue queue regarding (https://drupal.org/node/1209154) this where the maintainer has given some options for a potential fix and has tried a few options out, however there is still no proper fix for the problem.

The module already handles the back end and not allowing users to submit those values, the disabling is really only for visual reasons, so removing via js is a viable solution in this case.